# EditText error message with keyboard change affecting the theme/style

Tags: android

I have two edit texts, with validation to ensure that a value was entered for each box.

The problem is, when the keyboard is not displaying everything is ok, but when the keyboard is displayed the hover validation moves above the edittext and has a white background when it should be black.

Hopefully the images should show it better.

N.B it only happens on the below edittext, the top one is fine as the keyboard does not cover it once it is opened.

I have set the keyboard to not resize the screen, i.e.
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

**I think it may be an Acer issue on the Acer A501 tablet, as my Samsung Galaxy does not have this problem.**

```
    private TextWatcher mileageListener = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         String start = mStartMileage.getText().toString().trim();

        // check that start mileage has been entered
        if ("".equals(start)) {
            mStartMileage.setError(getText(R.string.validation_enter_start_mileage));
        }
    }
};
```

[image: Keyboard down]

[image: Keyboard up]

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your code, so post it. But before you do that, read [this](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What? That link isn't relevant..

Comment: It's relevant when you're posting code, which I asked you to do.

Comment: Apologies, I started reading it on my phone and it seemed to be irrelevant. I don't however have any code, this is just the default error code, all I am doing is calling "setError" on the input field. I will post it anyway

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `setError` but do you have to add anything to the XML layout to get that error box? or do you implement any custom styles in your `styles.xml`?

Comment: No, I've not done any layout for that whatsoever, it's just the default styling for an error as far as I'm aware. Literally all the code I have to get it there is within that TextWatcher. It may be caused by the fact I am not moving the window when the keyboard is added, ie the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" bit in the xml. I do need it in there though..